# Get Instance of circuit breaker from configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, openfeign

This is my configuration file.

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  instances:
    backendB:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 10
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
```

I am trying to create bean of my feign client using *Resilience4jFeign* but the circuit breaker object is initialized with default configuration as the name suggest *CircuitBreaker.ofDefaults*. I can't find any ways to get my instance of circuit breaker from configuration to an object.

```
    @Bean
    public CommunicationServiceProxy communicationServiceProxy(){
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = CircuitBreaker.ofDefaults("backendB");
        FeignDecorators decorators = FeignDecorators.builder()
                .withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker)
                .withFallbackFactory(CommunicationFallBack::new)
                .build();
        return Resilience4jFeign
                .builder(decorators)
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())

                .target(CommunicationServiceProxy.class, "http://localhost:8081");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it was using the CircuitBreakerRegistry.
Instead of creating registry using

```
CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults()
```

one need to autowired them.

```
        @Autowired
        private CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry;
```